# Neo4J - Java: Result incomplete

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a strange problem when I'm trying execute a cypher query in an java application.
The result.dumpToString()- method shows me the correct result.
But when I'm trying to iterate, the last node is always missing (for every executed query):

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {    
    System.out.println(((Node) row.get("A")));
    System.out.println(((Node) row.get("A")).getProperty("name").toString());           
}
```

The first output is correct. I see all nodes of  the result.
In the second output one node is missing, although I know, that the node has a "name"-property.

Has someone an idea? 
Thank you

Comment: did you run this in debugger with calling dumpToString()? that empties the result. It can only be iterated once. Are you in a transaction when you read these values?

Comment: can you also output: `System.out.println(((Node) row.get("A")).hasProperty("name")); `

Comment: I tried dumpToString() seperately to find out if it return all nodes or not. System.out.println(((Node) ow.get("A")).hasProperty("name")) -> One true-output is still missing.  I'm starting to think that there is some problem with the iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:
I was executing the query without beginning a Transaction.
Now it works. Nevertheless this is a strange behaviour.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

If you're missing a second output, it's likely that the value of that property is a string that is blank.  This line:

```
System.out.println(((Node) row.get("A")).getProperty("name").toString());
```

In the presence of an attribute "name" that is blank, this will print nothing at all (but a linefeed).

Also, the way you're doing this is a bit dangerous; keep in mind that in general nodes can be missing, so `getProperty("name")` can return null.  Meaning that when you call `toString()` on it, you can end up with a `NullPointerException`.  It's better to maybe write either this:

```
row.get("A").getProperty("name", "missing").toString();
```

That will return "missing" if the property is missing, or:

```
Object propValue = row.get("A").getProperty("name");
if(propValue != null) 
    System.out.println(propValue.toString());
else System.out.println("Missing name property");
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the NullPointerException.

Comment: Unfortunately the the name property is not a blank String. I checked it on the server. As already mentioned this happens not just for one query, but for all I want to execute.

Comment: What is the value on the server?   Update your question to include what sample data looks like, and what you expect.  Can you copy and past *exactly* what your program output looks like?